# Facebook SDK javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get a ID and NAME of User's FRIEND by random with  this code:

```
 // Acess Grantes of permissions code (not full (work))

function checkPerms(){
    var permsNeeded = ['email','public_profile','user_friends'];
//.... Continue of CheckPerms (  it works fine)

// this is User's Friend ID random ( no work) 
          FB.api(
        "/{user-id}/friends",
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*response.data.length);
            console.log(random);
            /* handle the result */
          }
        }
    );
// this is user NAME (work)
FB.api("/me", function(res){
            uname = (res.name)?res.name : '';
            console.log(uname);
        }); 
// This is User Friend's NAME ( no work)
    FB.api("/"+uid1, function(res){
            fname = (res.name)?res.name : '';
            console.log(fname);
        });
```

I only get console of uname, not others. can you please tell me what's wrong in my code / or if I need any permission from facebook to acess the data of friend ID's and names.

Comment: You can only get friends that have granted user_friends permission to the app. Not all friends

Comment: And how to get Who does not have granted this? Wich permission going to allow me to do so.  and if it does need review for facebook administrators?

Comment: You just need to ask the person to grant it

Comment: I want to ask one  user to access all their friend ID / PIC/ NAME  So how that's possible then?

Comment: Dis you read my first post. You can only get friends that has granted user_friends permission

Comment: Yes but I know there is way to  have acess one user';s friend Id/pic/name ( THOSE FRIENDS DOES NOT HAVE GRANTED ACESS) only 1 user has , so I use that user's friend picture to share on his content. Like:nametest.com

Comment: I understand that with user_friends permission I can acess friends only if those friends also have installed the app,  but how can I do without let them install it ?  I mean if someone for example : John granted permision to my app, so I use his profile and then his friend's profile ( This friend does not have permission to my app)  So?

Comment: You can't. You can only get friends that granted permission

Answer (score 0):

**Since v2.0 of the Graph API, you can only access friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too, for privacy reasons.**

There is a very detailed and complete answer about the issue in this thread: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for saving the data.

```
function GetFBLoginStatus() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                var email = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id, name, email' },
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(response.id);
                        console.log(response.name);
                        console.log(response.email);
                        alert("Funcion GetFB");

                        var id = document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>");
                        var nombreDePersona = document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField2.ClientID%>");
                        var email = document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField3.ClientID%>");

                        id.value = response.id;
                        nombreDePersona.value = response.name;
                        email.value = response.email;

                        __doPostBack("MyCall", "");
                }
            );
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //login function
            alert('login first');
        } else {
            //login function
            alert('login first');
        }
    }, true);
    }
```

I call a c# method and pass the values to hidden fields.